# Sub-Checkbox for Checkbox that is connected to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a checkbox which is connected to the database by using php and I also had sub-checkbox which is from HTML. My question is I have Laboratory checkbox that is connected from database, if a user checks/clicks it, it will appear all the sub-checkbox, if not it only hides.

Here's my php code for list checkboxes

```html
<?php
 $tsql = "select medTestName from medtest";
  $tstmt = $con->prepare($tsql);
  $tstmt->execute();
  $tstmt->bind_result($mtn);
$tstmt->store_result();
             
while ($tstmt->fetch()){
$d1= '<input type="checkbox" name="test[]"
                  value="'.$mtn.'">'.$mtn.'<br>';
echo $d1;
 }  
             
?>
```

and Here's my html code, list of sub-checkboxes

```html
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1"><span>Complete Blood Count</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2"><span>Blood Typing</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3"><span>Urinalysis</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4"><span>RPR/TPHA</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5"><span>Hepatitis B screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6"><span>Fasting Blood Sugar</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7"><span>Creatinine</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8"><span>Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9"><span>Triglyceride</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10"><span>VLDL</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11"><span>Blood Uric Acid</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12"><span>Anti-HAV Igm Screening</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13"><span>Anti HBaAg</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14"><span>Drug & Alcohol Test</span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15"><span>Stool Culture</span></div>
```

Image of the main check box

[image]

Image of database

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, toggle which checkboxes show under laboratory based on some setting in the database?

Comment: your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: in my first image, its from the php code which is connected to the database from the 1st image, when I check the laboratory checkbox the sub-checkbox must be shownm if its not it must stay hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if I understand what you want, but Perhaps this example can help you. (Instead of your sql code, I've used an array as an example.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var cbxMedTest = $("#formMedTest").find('input:checkbox');
            cbxMedTest.change(function() {
                if (this.id == 73) {
                    $("#subCheckBoxes").toggle();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="formMedTest">
    <?php
    $labTests = array(
        71 => "Vital Signs",
        72 => "Neuro-Psychological",
        73 => "Laboratory"
    );
    foreach ($labTests as $key => $labTest) {
        echo sprintf(
            '<input id="%1$d" type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="%2$s">%2$s',
            $key,
            $labTest
        );
    }
    ?>
    <div id="subCheckBoxes" style="display: none;">
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="1"><span>Complete Blood Count</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="2"><span>Blood Typing</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="3"><span>Urinalysis</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="4"><span>RPR/TPHA</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="5"><span>Hepatitis B screening</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="6"><span>Fasting Blood Sugar</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="7"><span>Creatinine</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="8"><span>Total Cholesterol(Low Cholesterol, High Cholesterol)</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="9"><span>Triglyceride</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="10"><span>VLDL</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="11"><span>Blood Uric Acid</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="12"><span>Anti-HAV Igm Screening</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="13"><span>Anti HBaAg</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="14"><span>Drug & Alcohol Test</span></div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" name="topic" value="15"><span>Stool Culture</span></div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```